# JToggleButton Tooltip being hidden by AWTGLCanvas

Tags: java, swing, awt, lwjgl

first time developer here, so I was hired over the summer to make this application that could find the layout of a building. I'm having a little problem with the JToggleButton's in my application and how they interact with the AWTGLcanvas.
The Problem being that after clicking into the AWTGLcanvas the labels get hidden behind the AWTGLcanvas.

[image: as seen here.]

The labels do show up like they should when I hover over them before clicking on the AWTGLcanvas. In response to this I tried adding `toolbar.requestFocusInWindow();` unfortunately this still didn't work.

(the cursor is hovering on the JtoggleButton but the screen capture I used gets rid of the cursor)

This is the code I'm using to make the button:

```
protected JToggleButton makeButton(String imageName, String actionCommand, String toolTipText) {
    String imgLocation = "res/" + imageName + ".png";
    JToggleButton button = new JToggleButton();
    button.setActionCommand(actionCommand);
    button.setToolTipText(toolTipText);
    try {
        Image image = ImageIO.read(new File(imgLocation));
        image = image.getScaledInstance(15,15, 0);
        button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    toggleButtons.add(button);
    return button;
}
```

Any help or suggestions are very appreciated

Comment: You will need to use just AWT I believe.  JAWT (or the Display class in LWJGL 2.x) is a heavyweight UI component.  Swing is lightweight.  In Java, heavyweight GUI components will always cover lightweight components.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, here is a link to a source that confirms this: http://forum.lwjgl.org/index.php?topic=5179.0